# How to make a real number parameter go 2 decimal precision?

Tags: numerics, formatting

I'm new at community and I'm starting with Mathematica.
I'm now having a trouble with a very simple problem which for many of you might be really obvious.

In documentation `N` suppose to give me a precision of the second parameter:

```
lfToMoneyValue[number_Real] := Module [{r},
    r = N[number, 2];
    r
]
```

I wish i have an "Out: 5.14" so i could afterward join 'R$' since it suppose to be in 'Reais' money currency

Could anyone help me? thank you alot

Comment: Possibly something like `NumberForm[...,{Infinity,2}]`. See also `AccountingForm`.

Comment: Try `lfToMoneyValue[number_Real] := ToString@Round[number, 0.01] <> " R$"`

Comment: Please clarify if you are looking for formatting of the number to two decimal places or if you want to actually round the number.

Comment: Im trying to get the SAME number with 2 decimal places, not rounded, if its really easier rounded, ok, but I could take both ways

Comment: eldo - That one acctually is working fine, thank you, still i wanted to know why i can do this with pi and i cant with another Real number